# Skipping an argument using the javascript .bind() method

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I can bind arguments to a function like so..

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) { console.log(arguments); }
foo = foo.bind(this, 'bar');
```

When called, we get this output...

```
foo('baz');
> { '0': 'bar', '1': 'baz' }
```

Is it possible to skip arguments in the .bind() function to achieve the following output?

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) { console.log(arguments); }
foo = foo.bind(this, 'bar', null, 'qux');
foo('baz', 'lel');
> { '0': 'bar', '1': 'baz', '2': 'lel', '3': 'qux' }
```

Comment: I don't think so.. if you don't need that argument why pass it

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Underscore's `_.partial`:

> Partially apply a function by filling in any number of its arguments, without changing its dynamic this value. **You may pass _ in your list of arguments to specify an argument that should not be pre-filled, but left open to supply at call-time.**

In your case:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) { console.log(arguments); }
foo = _.partial(foo, 'bar', _, 'qux');
foo('baz', 'lel');
> { '0': 'bar', '1': 'baz', '3': 'qux', '4': 'lel'}
```

Yes, I know this is not exactly what you said you wanted. You seem to want **both** arguments to be squeezed in where the `_` is. There is no good way around that other than explicitly specifying that two arguments will be filled in at the time of call:

```
foo = _.partial(foo, 'bar', _, _, 'qux');
```

I am not necessarily recommending that you use this, but at least you could take a look at their code and get some hints.

If you want to have predetermined arguments always come at the end, like `'qux'`, you will need some additional machinery. For instance, here's a little routine (using ES6, but you can adapt), that transforms a function into one where specified parameters are placed at the end of the argument list:

```
function partialEnd(fn, ...predefinedArgs) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(this, [...arguments, ...predefinedArgs]);
  };
}
```

You can use this like this:

```
function foo(a, b, c) { console.log(a + b + c); }
foo = partialEnd(foo, 3);
foo(1, 2) // outputs 6
```

You could combine this with `_.partial` using `_` placeholders to obtain an effect where some parameters are inserted into the argument list, and others are always placed at the end:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) { console.log(arguments); }
foo = _.partial(foo, 'bar', _, _);
foo = partialEnd(foo, 'lel');

foo('baz', 'lel');
> { '0': 'bar', '1': 'baz', '3': 'lel', '4': 'qux'}
```

Answer (score 2):

No such functionality exists in JavaScript, but it would be fairly straightforward to implement a function that does the same thing:

```
function curryWithNulls(fn, thisObj) {
  var curriedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var length = curriedArgs.length;

  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    for (var i = 0; i < length || args.length; i++) {
      if (i >= length || curriedArgs[i] === null) {
        curriedArgs[i] = args.shift();
      }
    }
    return fn.apply(thisObj, curriedArgs);
  }
}

function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

var curriedFoo = curryWithNulls(foo, this, 'bar', null, null, 'qux');
curriedFoo('baz', 'lel');
// => { '0': 'bar', '1': 'baz', '2': 'lel', '3': 'qux' }
```

This differs slightly from your example in that it requires a `null` for each skipped argument (whereas in your example you have a single `null` fill in for two arguments). This allows more complex constructions with curried arguments in any position, e.g.:

```
var curriedFoo2 = curryWithNulls(foo, this, null, 'bar', null, 'qux');
curriedFoo2('baz', 'lel');
// => { '0': 'baz', '1': 'bar', '2': 'lel', '3': 'qux' }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd just be binding the `null`.

The function's parameters are the function's parameters; binding a `null` does exactly that, it doesn't redefine the function, it returns a new one with the same signature.

Comment: "returns a new one with the same signature" --- is it the same actually? If you bind parameters, the "arity" of the new function reduces.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, I couldn't figure out how to word it. I meant that passing null in doesn't change the *original* function's arity.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a functional composition:

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) { console.log(arguments); }
var bar = function(arg2, arg4) { 
    return foo.bind(this, 'bar', arg2, 'qux')();
}
bar('baz', 'lel');
```

or, with modern syntax:

```
const foo = (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) => console.log(arguments);
const bar = (arg2, arg4) => foo.bind(this, 'bar', arg2, 'qux')();
bar('baz', 'lel');
```

or without bind at all:

```
const foo = (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) => console.log(arguments);
const bar = (arg2, arg4) => foo(this, 'bar', arg2, 'qux', arg4);
bar('baz', 'lel');
```

P.S. Don't forget to call your binded function (note these () after bind);